# Python - Create list of IPs based off starting IP

Tags: python, networking, ip-address

I spent a few hours researching, and this has stumped me.  Before I go down a new path, I'm looking for a best practice.

I ultimately want a list of IPs (*just* the IPs) when given a starting IP, based off the quantity of items in a list.

I've been using the `ipaddress` module; here's the nearest I've gotten..

```
import ipaddress
IP_Start = 192.168.1.1
hostnames = [hostname1, hostname2, hostname3]
list_of_ips = []
my_range = range(len(hostnames))
for ips in my_range:
    list_of_ips.append(ipaddress.ip_address(IP_Start) + my_range[ips])
print(list_of_ips)
```

Output:

```
list_of_ips = [IPv4Address('192.168.1.1'), IPv4Address('192.168.1.2'), IPv4Address('192.168.1.3')]
```

For some reason, I cannot strip "IPv4Address(' ')" out of the list of strings; my output may not be a traditional list.  When using `str.replace`, I get weird errors and figure `replac`ing is probably not the best practice.

I feel like if I ditch the `ipaddress` module, there would be a much simpler way of doing this.  What would be a better way of doing this so my output is simply

```
list_of_ips = [192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IPv4Address` is the data type of the object returned.  That is the name of a class; the display function for that class says that it returns the format you see, with the IP address as a string.  You need to look up the class to find a method (function) or attribute (data field) to give you the IP address as a string, without the rest of the object tagging along.

The simplest way to do this is to convert to `str`:

```
for ips in my_range:
    list_of_ips.append(str(ipaddress.ip_address(IP_Start)) ... )
```

Comment: LOL, wow!! This is great, it does exactly what I was looking for and it's just adding 5 characters of code.  Amazing.  The "str" ending ) goes at the end of my line, so looks like..
    for ips in my_range:
    list_of_ips.append(str(ipaddress.ip_address(IP_Start) + my_range[ips]))

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it with builtins only

start with a function to convert an IP address to a long integer, and another function to convert a long integer back into an IP address

```
import socket,struct
def ip_to_int(ip_address):
    return struct.unpack('!I', socket.inet_aton(ip_address))[0]


def int_to_ip(int_value):
    return socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('!I', int_value))
```

then all you need to do is iterate over your range

```
def iter_ip_range(start_address, end_address):
    for i in range(ip_to_int(start_address), ip_to_int(end_address) + 1):
        yield int_to_ip(i)
```

and just use it

```
print(list(iter_ip_range("192.168.11.12","192.168.11.22")))
```

Comment: Whoa, thank you very much.  I am saving this snippet!  This will come in handy for something later on in the process, I used Prune's solution below which barely modifies what I have to make it work.  Thanks for your time!